# AWS CDK custom resource backed by a Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

CloudFormation itslef supports custom resources backed by lambda or ec2.

However, i could not find something similar on AWS CDK. The only way it seems you can define custom resources is now by specifying resources, actions and paramters.

Does it mean that with a current CDK I might be able to choose whether to call a lambda function or a specific "CLI" command ? Can anyone explain the fundamental logic behind custom resources in AWS CDK?

P.S. I perfectly know how to operate custom resources on CloudFormation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The custom resource you are referencing to is located in the package [`@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1.14.0/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation/README.md).

You can find a TypeScript example in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudformation-readme.html#example):

```ts
interface CopyOperationProps {
  sourceBucket: IBucket;
  targetBucket: IBucket;
}

class CopyOperation extends Construct {
  constructor(parent: Construct, name: string, props: CopyOperationProps) {
    super(parent, name);

    const lambdaProvider = new lambda.SingletonFunction(this, 'Provider', {
      uuid: 'f7d4f730-4ee1-11e8-9c2d-fa7ae01bbebc',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('../copy-handler'),
      handler: 'index.handler',
      timeout: Duration.seconds(60),
    });

    new CustomResource(this, 'Resource', {
      provider: CustomResourceProvider.lambda(lambdaProvider),
      properties: {
        sourceBucketArn: props.sourceBucket.bucketArn,
        targetBucketArn: props.targetBucket.bucketArn,
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is so much more convenient rather than using Tropospheres custom resources.

Comment: @jogold In this way, if I'm returning something... Do you know how can I get the value returned by the lambda? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `getAtt()` method on the `CustomResource`, `getAtt('myAttribute')` if you are returning `{ myAttribute: '...' }` as data in your custom resource.

Comment: Would be great to have this question answered again, as the code sample has deprecated...